Manage Tile Cache tool output not displaying
I have a Mosaic data set which is 83gb and is displaying correctly. I want to get it on ArcGIS Online using the following work flow:
Create Tile Cache Scheme-> Manage Tile Cache-> Export Tile Cache-> Share Package
When I use the Manage Tile Cache tool it takes about 10 hours, but outputs a Raster dataset which is 26gb and not displaying at all. I have tried: running it with the mosaic data set displaying in the data frame, defining an area of interest, using the ArcGIS Online Tile Scheme, and running these tools on both 10.7 and Pro.
The output from this SHOULD display right? I have also tried just exporting the output from the Manage Tile Cache tool to a TPKX using the Export Tile Cache tool and the output from that will also not display. Once I started using an area of interest I could right click on the output Raster Dataset and use the ‘zoom to layer’ feature to zoom to where the display SHOULD be, but it still is displaying nothing.
We have been running this process on our production server which I understand is not a best practice, is it possible it is not completing correctly because our overnight scripts and it are competing for CPU?
I can have this process moved off our production server, but I also want to make sure I am not making a more basic mistake when using this tool, especially if there is configuration I need to preforming the Raster Data Set after it has been produced.
